# maximum area of semi-circle in square

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

I'm struggling the with the following question:

Given is a square with length $a$. Now I want to find a semi-circle with the max. area. Looks like this:

http://tube.geogebra.org/material/show/id/222093

Now I want to prove, that the semi-circle is the best one (max. area) but have no idea, how to start.

Comment: http://www.qbyte.org/puzzles/p153s.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We solve the "dual" problem of finding the smallest square containing the semicircle $H:=\{(x,y)|x^2+y^2\leq 1, \ x\geq0\}$. Drawing supporting lines to $H$ having slopes $\phi$ and $\phi+{\pi\over2}$ with respect to the horizontal we see that the smallest square containing $H$ and having sides with these slopes has  side length
$$s(\phi)=\max\{1+\cos\phi,1+\sin\phi\}\qquad \bigl(0\leq\phi\leq{\pi\over2}\bigr)\ .$$
This is minimal when $\phi={\pi\over4}$, so that we obtain $s_{\min}=1+{\sqrt{2}\over2}$.

Returning to the original problem, where the side length $a$ of the square is given, we can say that the semicircle of maximal area inscribed in the square has its diameter parallel to a diagonal, and its radius $r_{\max}$ is given by
$$r_{\max}=\bigl(2-\sqrt{2}\bigr)\>a\ .$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure how to prove that the construction in your worksheet has the max. area (I assume it does). However, to answer the question in your worksheet

> What is the position of the center of the semicircle that produces the largest inscribed area in the square? What is this area?

For a given center $c=(n,n)$ you get a radius of $r=\sqrt2n$. You can maximize this by setting:
$$n+r=n+\sqrt2n=1$$
$$n=\sqrt2-1\approx0.41421 $$
and the area of the half-circle can then be computed knowing $r$.